# Excel copy all values from one main sheet to various other sheets if they are a certain colour

Tags: vba, excel

Would really appreciate a solution to the below:

I am looking to have 8 sheets.

1. Main sheet that has all jobs, these are all currently sorted into the following colours :

Red - live
Green - invoiced/complete
Blue - quoted
Black - enquiry
Grey - dead/ lost
Purple - work in progress
Yellow - Retention

what i would like to do is keep the main sheet and have a sheet for each of the above. when the text becomes red for example i would like it to be transfered to the live sheet and vica versa for the rest. this should be in a macro

can anyone help?

Many thanks,

Comment: This is more tricky than it first appears because presumably when some work 'becomes red' you would like it removed from whatever (sub-) sheet it is on as well as being inserted into the red sub-sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You say "when the text becomes red " so possibly this is a conditional format? 
In any case, what you need to do is to attach code to the main sheet's Calculate event . This code should do the following

look at the activecell's  color element that you mean (font, background, conditional formating, etc)
Based on that color, copy the entire row to the appropriate sheet
(Can you assume the sheets already exist?)

You will probably need a Select Case Statement. I would declare a worksheet variable and then SET it to the appropriate sheet in the select
and then

Activecell.entirerow.copy ws.cells(ws.rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0)

will copy the row to the desired sheet at the bottom of any existing rows.

Have a try and come back with code if you get stuck

EDIT:  Sorry I missed the "click a button" part. You can ignore the bit about the sheets calculate event - just attach your code to the button. The only thing to worry about then is that you will need to run through all the used rows of the sheet, since there might be more than one coloured row when you click on the button.

Comment: Hi,   Thanks for the reply. In answer to your question. Its the texts that are coloured across rows in multiple cells. for example a whole row maybe red. i would like to have a macro that i click and it will copy across the coloured rows into the correct sheet.i will have a go, i haven't done any coding in years so it wont be great haha.